# How to restrict specific pages in WordPress website by login registration form?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I created a WordPress based website. I used many plugins for page restriction. Basically, I want to show login registration form on restriction pages and after login or registration, it should redirect to this specific page, not go to my account or profile page. plz, give me any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this, is to access your web files via FTP and edit your `.htaccess` file.  Here are the required steps:

1. Download and Install [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)
2. Once you open FileZilla, head to `File > Site Manager`
3. Enter the following details:
   Host:  Your Hosting IP Address
   Protocol:  SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol (This is more secure than the login options, within the opening/main page)
   Logon Type:  Ask for password
   User: root
   Password:  Leave blank
4. Select 'Connect' and enter your Root Password.
5. If this does not work, ask your Hosting Company for assistance.
6. Once logged in, you will need to access your root directory.  This will typically be somewhere like `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs`.  Again, seek assistance, from your Hosting Company, if the location does not exist or if you cannot find such directory.
7. If this directory has a `.htaccess` file, drag it over to your computer ready for editing.  If the directory does not have a `.htaccess` file, simply create one.
8. Open up the `.htaccess` file, using a file editor.  I find [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is great for simply tasks/beginners.
9. What you now need to do, is identify all of the *restricted URLs* you want to redirect, as well as their redirected URLs.
10. Once you have listed the above, as necessary, enter them into your `.htaccess` file, using the following template:

`# Redirect Description
Redirect /old-url/ /new-url/`

11. Simply replace 'old-url' with the restricted URL page and enter the redirected URL, where 'new-url' is.
12. Repeat this, for every redirection you require.
13. Once you have completed all of your redirects, save the file and drag it over to your root directory.  As stated above, this would typically be somewhere like `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs`.

I have just tested my suggestion and can confirm, it works.